# Why the second image is not being dropped in the correct position in html and Javascipt?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in which is implemented a simple drag and drop with an image.
for some reason the first image works the second no, when I drug it inside the div boxes and It display outside of it.
Someone know why the second image is displayed in bad with respect to the first one?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  alert("Wrong")
}
```

```css
#div4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 905px;
  top: 900px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color:white;
}
 #getData {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #4f4d4d;
    left: 400px;
    top = 500px
}
```

```html
<h3>Drag the GeekforGeeks image into the rectangle:</h3>
<div id="getData" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="center" src="Immagine.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100">
<img src="Immagine.png" id ="prova" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="position:absolute; margin-left:20.6%" width ="100" height="100">
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean with "working" and what is "displayed in bad"? Without knowing what you expect to happen, there is nothing good or bad.

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate more and provide more details

Comment: @MohammedAlwedaei If you open full screen you will notice that the second image, for some reason when It is dropped on the div instead of being dropd inside the box it is dropped outside

Comment: I found the solution. Please task a look at the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution isn't that hard.
You just tried to add a margin between the first image and the second image. And this made the image appear as if it was not appended to the parent div.
As you can see in the figure both images are being appended to the div.
[image: Image appending]

So you either remove the left margin on the second image. or remove it when it is being dropped.

Here is a working example of what I mean

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      }

      function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        
        //Set the value of your margin here
        //Don't raise the value so it doesn't overlap the container
        //And you can change the value from px to rem, em...
        document.getElementById(data).style.margin = 0 + "px";
        alert("Wrong");
      }
```

```css
 #div4 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 905px;
        top: 900px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 125px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        background-color: white;
      }
      #getData {
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 5px solid #4f4d4d;
        left: 400px;
        top: 500px;
      }
```

```html
    <h3>Drag the GeekforGeeks image into the rectangle:</h3>
    <div id="getData" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <img
      id="center"
      src="Immagine.png"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="drag(event)"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
    <img
      src="Immagine.png"
      id="prova"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="drag(event)"
      style="position: absolute; margin-left: 20.6%"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```